# How to connect Google TV remote app with Google TV emulator

Tags: networking, android-emulator, google-tv, remote-control

As the title suggests, I have been unable to connect (and pair) the [google tv remote app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.tvremote&hl=en) with a Google TV emulator running on Ubuntu. I understand that the emulator runs on its own sub-network and therefore has to use redirections in order to connect with anything outside its network.

I have tried the following:

1) Remote control app running on device,

2) Remote control app running on android emulator on same machine as the google tv emulator (For this I had to use a modified version of the app, since there is no wifi on the emulator and the official app would close without wifi)

In configuration (2) I have somehow managed to establish a connection with the tv emulator by using telnet and redirection commands (see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#redirections)). However the app fails while trying to establish pairing as it tries to build a socket at a new (random) port which is not redirected (I assume).

I would firstly like to know how to find which ports to route for the google tv remote app to successfully connect with the TV emulator. And then how would the pairing action succeed in connecting the controller with the TV emulator through a new socket (which I couldn't redirect)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not supported. If you are working on a GoogleTV application that requires this feature, please fill out the form at goo.gl/tVw4i.

Comment: So when you say it isn't supported, you're saying I can not develop multi-screen apps for the google tv platform with just the Google TV emulator? I would require an actual google tv device??

Comment: Is there a way to develop such apps without having the Google TV device?

Comment: I meant its not supported for emulator. You would need a GoogleTV device to test multi-screen apps. That is the reason I suggested filling out the form to let us know of your app idea and see how we can help.