# Connect Google TV Remote (phone) to Google TV emulator

Tags: networking, android-emulator, remote-debugging, google-tv, remote-control

Is there a way to connect Google TV Remote App to a Google TV emulator?

I tried to configure the emulator network to be accessible from outside without success.

I know that this question has already been made here:
[How to connect Google TV remote app with Google TV emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017032/how-to-connect-google-tv-remote-app-with-google-tv-emulator)
but I was hoping that 6 months later, maybe something new has emerged.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible because emulator does not support it. Its best to use a Google TV device to debug second screen applications.